# Is there a better way to do this (may be using methods)?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, if-statement, methods

C#
Here orders is a JSON object. I have 3 string which are probably int and I am validating that (using extension methods), however I seem to be repeating the same code for each of the variables. I am looking a way to optimise this as somehow it seems to verbose.
Also can I consume date or the double check too in this?

```
            int itemNumber;
            int customer;
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            string dateFormatted = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            int itemQuantity;
            double itemCost;

            bool result;
            int orderNum = int.Parse(orders.OrderNumber);//convert string to int

            int validInt;
            double validDbl;

            //loop through each of the orders
            foreach (var order in orders.OrderDetails)
            {
                string item = order.ItemNumber;
                string cusNumber = order.CustomerNumber;
                string orderDate = order.OrderDate;
                string quantity = order.Quantity;
                string cost = order.Cost;

                //string field;

                result = item.isNumber();

                // Validate item number
                validInt = validate(item);


                //}
                int counter = 0;
                if (validInt != 0)
                {
                    itemNumber = validInt;
                    counter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    errMessage = $"{item} is not a valid integer value.";
                    errors.Add(errMessage);

                }

                // Validate customer number
                validInt = validate(cusNumber);
              
                if (validInt != 0)
                {
                    customer = validInt;
                    counter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    errMessage = $"{cusNumber} is not a valid integer value.";
                    errors.Add(errMessage);
                }

                

                validInt = validate(quantity);
                if (validInt != 0)
                {
                    itemQuantity = validInt;
                    counter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    errMessage = $"{quantity} is not a valid integer value.";
                    errors.Add(errMessage);
                }

                validDbl = isDouble(cost);
                if (validDbl != 0)
                {
                    itemCost= validDbl;
                    counter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    errMessage = $"{quantity} is not a valid integer value.";
                    errors.Add(errMessage);
                }



            }
```

I shall then be using the counter and the errMessage to display correct Orders if the counter = total count of items in the JSON object(array).

Comment: Why are you checking `validInt` against 0 repeatedly?

Comment: And you literally have a copy of the exact same code placed below the original one. Please clean up your code example to the shortest one that can illustrate your question.

Comment: my method either returns the actual data value or a 0. So, the validInt is to check that. My question is basically around is there a batter way to represent  this repetition. So, that I can shorten the code.

Comment: I don't see a return statement in your example so your intention is unclear. What I meant in my comments is that you should first combine all those duplicate if statements together as checking them over and over again are not only slow but also pointless.

Comment: could you please suggest how to get rid of the duplicate ifs? Thanks.

Comment: Right now you are checking it and do something, and before you do another thing, you check the same condition again. Why can't you check it only once and do all you need to do in one go instead of splitting them all up and checking the same condition over and over again?

Comment: It is because the data values to check are different such as itemNumber, custNumber, etc. and based each of the validation the errMessage also changes to accommodate the data field name. (I have deleted the one extra repetition block as it was copied from above loop by mistake). Thanks.

Comment: What data value? You are checking if `validInt` is not 0 three times in a row. Combine those checks. It is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A smarter validate

```
 static bool validate(string input, out int field, ref int counter, List<string> errors){
       bool ok = Int32.TryParse(input, out field);
       if(ok){
            counter++;
       }else{
           errors.Add($"{input} is not a valid integer value.");
       }
       return ok; // just in case we need it
   }
```

now

```
    validate(item, out itemNumber, ref counter, errors);
    validate(cusNumber, out customer, ref counter, errors);
    validate(quantity, out itemQuantity, ref counter, errors);
    .....
```

or you could make validate a member function and have counter and errors as member variables, in that case they dont need to be passed as args